# Fail adding objects to an ArrayList. Always copies the same

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist

To add different objects from the database to an `ArrayList` this is the code that I use:

```
try {
    Statement stat = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Id, Username, FirstName, LastName FROM USER WHERE Username LIKE '%"+name+"%' or FirstName LIKE '%"+name+"%' or LastName LIKE '%"+name+"%'");
    while (rs.next()){
        finded.setUsername(rs.getString("Username"));
        finded.setFirstName(rs.getString("FirstName"));
        finded.setLastName(rs.getString("LastName"));
        finded.setId(rs.getInt("Id"));
        findList.add(finded);
        Log.d("this is the content of the List:",((Integer) findList.get(j).getId()).toString());
        Log.d("this is the content of the List 0:",((Integer) findList.get(0).getId()).toString());

    }
    con.close();
```

And this is what the Log.d gives me each time.

```
10-18 08:31:39.407: D/this is the content of the List:(427): 3
10-18 08:31:39.407: D/this is the content of the List 0:(427): 3
10-18 08:31:39.427: D/this is the content of the List:(427): 15
10-18 08:31:39.427: D/this is the content of the List 0:(427): 15
10-18 08:31:39.437: D/this is the content of the List:(427): 13
10-18 08:31:39.437: D/this is the content of the List 0:(427): 13
10-18 08:31:39.447: D/this is the content of the List:(427): 50
10-18 08:31:39.447: D/this is the content of the List 0:(427): 50
10-18 08:31:39.460: D/this is the content of the List:(427): 34
10-18 08:31:39.460: D/this is the content of the List 0:(427): 34
10-18 08:31:39.467: D/this is the content of the List:(427): 49
10-18 08:31:39.467: D/this is the content of the List 0:(427): 49
10-18 08:31:39.479: D/this is the content of the List:(427): 53
10-18 08:31:39.479: D/this is the content of the List 0:(427): 53
```

As you can see it copies the same object in all the position of the `ArrayList`. I tried also to do it with `findList.add(index, finded)` (`index` is an `int` who is incrementing) But I get the same result.

Comment: Heiko's answer below seems correct. If you add the SAME object again and again, then when you setUsername, you set it for everywhere that this object is added. That's why you need to create a NEW object for each time you insert it, as described by Heiko.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new object for `finded`inside the loop

```
while (rs.next()){
    finded = new Finded();   // <<-- here
    finded.setUsername(rs.getString("Username"));
```

otherwise you just add the same object over and over again

Answer (score 2):

Change to following:

```
 int j=0;
 try {
                Statement stat = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Id, Username, FirstName, LastName FROM USER WHERE Username LIKE '%"+name+"%' or FirstName LIKE '%"+name+"%' or LastName LIKE '%"+name+"%'");
                while (rs.next()){
                    Finded finded=new Finded();
                    finded.setUsername(rs.getString("Username"));
                    finded.setFirstName(rs.getString("FirstName"));
                    finded.setLastName(rs.getString("LastName"));
                    finded.setId(rs.getInt("Id"));
                    findList.add(finded);
                    Log.d("this is the content of the List:",((Integer) findList.get(j).getId()).toString());
                    Log.d("this is the content of the List 0:",((Integer) findList.get(0).getId()).toString());
j++;
                }
                con.close();
```

Comment: I vote for this answer, as not only do all your list entries point to the same object, j was not being incremented so you keep displaying entry [0].

Answer (score 1):

Your query is returning multiple records but, you are overriding the `finded` object instead of creating a new one inside your loop.
Create a new object inside your loop

```
Finded finded =null;
while (rs.next()){
                    finded = new Finded();
                    finded.setUsername(rs.getString("Username"));
                    finded.setFirstName(rs.getString("FirstName"));
                    finded.setLastName(rs.getString("LastName"));
                    finded.setId(rs.getInt("Id"));
                    findList.add(finded);


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use "group by" instead of "distinct".

select .... from ... group by ...

How about try this?